# Dynamic list of multiple PDF author

Tags: hyperref

I want to build a document class allowing the use of multiple authors. To this end, I created a command to add as many authors as we want, storing them into commands like `\authornamei`, `\authornameii`, etc. This part is done, but now I want to put this list into the PDF Author field. My idea was to use the `\hypersetup` command of the package `\hyperref` but it's acting weird. There's surely something I don't understand here and that's why I need your help!

This minimal working example will probably help:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{L}
\newcommand{\aaai}{first}
\newcommand{\aaaii}{second}
\setcounter{L}{2}

\newcounter{C}

\newcommand{\buildlist}{%
    \csname aaa\roman{C}\endcsname%
    \ifnum\value{C}<\value{L}%
        ,%
        \stepcounter{C}%
        \buildlist%
    \fi%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{C}{1}
    \let\ccc\buildlist

    ccc: \ccc

    \hypersetup{
        pdfauthor = {\ccc}
    }
\end{document}
```

With this code, I get a PDF with content as expected: `ccc: first,second`. However, in the PDF data, the Author field is just `second`. The only explanation I find for this is that `\ccc` is computed again. Then, as a workaround, I tried to reset the counter to 1 right before the `\hypersetup` call, but it throws a compilation error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.30    }
```

I get the same error if I don't try to display `\ccc` first. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N\g_jeremy_authors_seq
\NewDocumentCommand\newauthor { m }
{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn  \g_jeremy_authors_seq { #1 }
}

\newcommand\authorlist
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \g_jeremy_authors_seq{,~}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newauthor{first}
\newauthor{second}
\usepackage{hyperref}

 \hypersetup{
        pdfauthor = {\authorlist}
    }

\begin{document}
\authorlist
\end{document}
```